# How can I conditionally select attributes from html nodes with rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

Is there a way to use OR with `html_attr()`? In this MRE, I only want the nodes with "drink" or "food" attributes.

That is, with the following data, I'd like to do something like `mydata %>% html_nodes("mynode") %>% html_attr("drink" or "food" otherwise skip)`, and get:

```
[1] "tea"    "coffee" "egg"    "toast" 

> mydata
{xml_document}
<allitems>
[1] <mynode drink="tea"/>
[2] <mynode dessert="cookie"/>
[3] <mynode drink="coffee"/>
[4] <mynode spice="pepper"/>
[5] <mynode food="egg"/>
[6] <mynode food="toast"/>
```

Can I do this without pulling out the drink and food attributes separately, combining the vectors, and removing NAs?

Comment: in the end it will be sthg like `...%in% c("drink", "food")`, but to enable testing it you should make your example reproducible,...

Comment: How do I make xml data reproducible?

Comment: you could use `dput()` to share `mydata`.

Comment: useful reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170353/how-can-i-conditionally-select-attributes-from-html-nodes-with-rvest

Comment: That just links back to this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to suggest using the `xml2` package, which is a dependency of `rvest` I believe.

Making reproducible by coercing to `HTML` with `package::htmltools`

```
a <- htmltools::HTML(
     '<mynode drink="tea"/>
      <mynode dessert="cookie"/>
      <mynode drink="coffee"/>
      <mynode spice="pepper"/>
      <mynode food="egg"/>
      <mynode food="toast"/>')
```

Now using an `xpath` selector we can extract all nodes with an attribute or `food` or `drink`.

```
> read_html(a) %>% xml_find_all('//*[@food or @drink]')
{xml_nodeset (4)}
[1] <mynode drink="tea"></mynode>
[2] <mynode drink="coffee"></mynode>
[3] <mynode food="egg"></mynode>
[4] <mynode food="toast"></mynode>
```

To get to the attribute values:

```
> read_html(a) %>% xml_find_all('//*[@food or @drink]') %>% 
     xml_attrs() %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)
[1] "tea"    "coffee" "egg"    "toast"
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, but you should google `xpath selectors` to get a good idea of what all can be done.